# Is there a kind of table about configurations similar to the example I gave below?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

If MALDI is used as an ionization method, then TOF as an analyzer is suitable since the MALDI creates singly charged ions which have high m/z ratio and only TOF can analyze that ions, and multichannel plate should be used because the TOF is very quick and MCP's duty time is enough to capture all ions.

Is there a kind of table about configurations similar to the example I gave above? A table with reasons would be great but not certainly necessary.

Comment: I always like to see mass spectrometry questions but am confused about what you are asking for.  MALDI ionization can be used with a variety of mass spectrometry detectors, including TOFs, linear ion traps, Orbitraps, and probably even quadrupoles.

Comment: Are you asking for a table with ionisation techniques on one axis and analysation techniques on the other? AFAIK, all ionisation techniques are compatible with all analysation techniques, but some have no realistic use cases.

Comment: The question is quite old. I was studying MS and was looking at my lecture notes then I observed that my lecturer had something like a table in his mind. From what I've learned there are non-offical "X ionisation technique + Y analyzer + Z detector is the best combination" kind of statements. Seeing all the combination was supposed to light a bulb on designing a theoretical setup and reasoning each component.